# Play Framework 2.2.x multiple route files

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

I've read through the Play! For Scala book's section on modules and I can't seem to figure out how to import the routes from a referenced module. I've set up my module as a library dependency in my build.sbt file and I've tried to import the route in my routes file like so

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.2.0", 
  "default" % "mymodule" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

routes

```
...
-> /api/mymodule mymodule.routes
```

mymodule contains a routing file called mymodule.routes. I don't really see how this could work however I don't fully understand what's going on so I'm not sure what else to try.

I've also tried abandoning the routes file in my referenced module and sticking a new routing file in my conf directory called mymodule.routes and that doesn't work either. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe to take advantage of routing from a module, you have to structure your project as a multi-project build, not a library dependency.

Take a look at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTSubProjects for how to setup the multi-project build.

Comment: What about having multiple routing files? It looks like you should be able to do this according to this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211734/play-framework-split-routes-in-multiple-files-without-sub-projects

Comment: Oh, it looks like this works:

-> /api/mymodule mymodule.Routes

Comment: Were you able to reference routes from the library dependency or did you end up splitting it out into a module?

Comment: Yep, I can reference the route file in the library dependency.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate more on how were you able to make routes files provided in lib dependency? Perhaps an example would be helpful. We are struggling so far to do same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the routes file from your referenced module in the default routes file? If not try:

```
include "api/mymodule/routes"
```