# Play 2 - Include another routes file in conf/routes

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I've got 50+ legacy Spring w/JPA domain models I'm bringing into a new Java Play app to build a CRUD interface around. After examining several options I decided I wanted to write some code to generate the 50+ controllers and ~50*5 view files whenever a make a change to a set of templates. Basically I want to scaffold the code kind of how I used to do it in RoR. I've written this is as an executable Java class (ie with a main()).

As there will be 250+ routes required for this project is there a way to put all of the generated routes in a separate routes file that would then be included in 'conf/routes'? That way I can separate the generated routes for these legacy domain models from the ones I add to 'conf/routes' manually.

A related question would be: Is there anything similar to RoR's "resources :cities" declaration in routes.rb in Play? (FYI in RoR this creates all of the CRUD routes for the model declared as a resource)

The app is currently running Play 2.3.0 but we have plans to move it to 2.4.2 once we can make Guice and Spring play nice together.

Comment: Do you want to add those routes to your additional route file dynamically during runtime?

Comment: No that would not be necessary. The routes will be generated with a script during during development.

Comment: I've never done something like this myself. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615280/play-framework-2-2-x-multiple-route-files is a help?

Comment: Here's a good post from James Roper: https://jazzy.id.au/2013/05/08/advanced_routing_in_play_framework.html

Comment: You can include routes from sub-projects or other routes files with the '-> /subproject  subproject.Routes' syntax as shown in examples here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SBTSubProjects

TBH I don't have this working in my project yet, but hopefully the link will help others.

I also want to refer to controllers in the root project from my subproject.Routes but I may have to rethink that requirement because I don't think that will work (b/c there is a cyclic dependency)