# How to handle api version cleanly in url in Play Framework (2.4.x)?

Tags: scala, playframework

So currently my routes file is a series of routes with a hardcoded version.

```
GET    /v1/companies/$id<[-a-zA-Z0-9]+>/etwasX    controllers.Company.etwasX(id:String, q: Option[String])
GET    /v1/companies/$id<[-a-zA-Z0-9]+>/etwasY    controllers.Company.etwasY(id:String, q: Option[String])
```

I have about some 30 routes defined. Now I would like to support different versions. I thought I could simply do this:

```
GET    /v<[0-9]+>/companies/$id<[-a-zA-Z0-9]+>/etwasX    controllers.Company.etwasX(id:String, q: Option[String])
```

But it doesn't work, and if I define it with a $

```
GET    /v$version<[0-9]+>/companies/$id<[-a-zA-Z0-9]+>/etwasX    controllers.Company.etwasX(id:String, q: Option[String])
```

Then it complains I don't have a version parameter in the controller method. Is there any other way beside specifying the version in every controller method?

If not, is there a way I could somehow automatically generate the routes for all the supported versions (assuming for now that they would have the same definition)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a lot of discussion about if HTTP (REST) APIs should be versioned using the URL or not, using a path prefix like you are doing. But, if you decide that URL versioning is the right answer to your case, you can more easily achieve that by [splitting your routes in multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20223621/4600).

That way, you would have the following `conf/routes` file:

```
# SomeController.index is an endpoint which is not versioned
GET    /      controllers.SomeController.index
->     /v1    api.Routes
```

And also, you would have a `conf/api.routes` file with the following:

```
GET    /companies/$id<[-a-zA-Z0-9]+>/etwasX    controllers.Company.etwasX(id:String, q: Option[String])
GET    /companies/$id<[-a-zA-Z0-9]+>/etwasY    controllers.Company.etwasY(id:String, q: Option[String])
```

What we are doing here is basically creating a path (`v1`) to the API routes defined in `api.routes`. Then, when you decide that you need a `v2`, you just need to edit your sub-routes prefix.

Comment: I wasn't able to add V2 into the same conf/routes file.

As in this gist: https://gist.github.com/jonandersen/4f60c47746de388dc9636a082b5ac30f
Is there a way to support multiple versions, in the same app?